# How do I use integrate.cumtrapz correctly?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have tried to do a trapeze integration with f(x)=x^2, where I know how the antiderivative looks like, so F(x) = (1/3)x^3

Here's my code, just like I tried:

```
import scipy.integrate as it
p=x**2
l=it.cumtrapz(p, initial=0)

plt.plot(l)
```

Then I get this plot (1):

[plot from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCGAn.png)

But the plot should look like this (2). The axis designations are different and the intersection point in the coordinate origin (0,0) is not the same as in (1).:

[plot(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf89X.png)

How can I achieve with my code that the graph from (1) looks exactly like (2)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use scipy.integrate.trapz instead of scipy.integrate.cumtrapz